# postgresql-pgadmin 4 insert data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert data using for example(it works in the tutorial on yt):

```
INSERT INTO cars (name ,price) 
VALUES ('renault' , '10000')
```

but it doesn't work in my database and I have no idea why, instead of this I have to use:

```
INSERT INTO public."cars" VALUES ('renault','10000')
```

So my question is: What's the difference between public."cars" and just cars?

Comment: In Postgres there is no difference between `"cars"` and `cars`. Also what is the error you get when you run the first statement? **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I've solved my problem, there is some difference between capital letter and lowercase when we create tables and that was my problem, first I've created table "Cars".I didn't realised that column which aren't double-quoted are folded to lower case in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between quoted and unquoted identifiers is that the former allow arbitrary characters and SQL keywords and are not folded to lower case. None of this applies in your case.

The only difference is that in one case you qualify the name with a schema, so perhaps your problem is that there is another table `cars` on your `search_path`.

It is impossible to say more, because “does not work” is too unspecific.